# Does C# with NUnit supports Allure features like Steps, Features/Stories, Parameters

Tags: allure

We use Visual studio, NUnit, Selenium web driver and C# to write our test code. My question is can we use Allure feature such as Steps, Features/Stories, Parameters with our stack or is it just supported with java based test framework?

I dont see any documentation about the implementation of these features other then java.

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use Allure features.

Take a look at the [Allure C# port](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp-commons). You will also need the [Nunit adapter](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-nunit2).

The events you can use are listed [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp-commons/wiki/Events).